# What is the best course of action when Jeep Wrangler transmission has been driven with low fluid levels

Tags: automatic-transmission, jeep, computer, transmission-fluid, wrangler

A small pinhole occurred in the transmission cooler lines near the radiator in a 2012 Jeep Wrangler. It has automatic transmission.

Over time the owner kept adding transmission fluid when needed and kept driving the Jeep.

Over time the pinhole got worse and worse.

At times it would be driven to the point where the transmission would slip because of the low fluid levels.

At other times the wrong fluid (Mercon, Dexron III and Mercon V) was probably added.

The leak was finally fixed, and the transmission was filled.

Now the engine computer is throwing codes for the shift solenoids, and codes for other transmission issues could be thrown as well.

In my opinion replacing solenoids will not help because there probably could be clutch wear that the solenoids can't overcome.

I think draining the fluid (and torque converter) and replacing with proper fluid might work, however, in the opinion of others here, especially those who work on Chrysler transmissions a lot, is it too late for this? Is a rebuild the only way to restore proper operation? Or what would you do? Cost is a big factor. We need the cheapest way out.

However, if the recommendation is to rebuild; The Jeep is still drivable. And if the recommendation is a rebuild, wouldn't there be nothing to lose by driving it the way it is until money can be found to rebuild? The shifting is a little erratic and delayed at times, but it will still get places.